# perl $CGI::POST_MAX all parameters

Tags: perl

I have troubles with using $CGI::POST_MAX in perl. I have form for the uploading files. 
I need to pass on more than one parameter to the script.
I set variable $CGI::POST_MAX to some value. It works fine, but when the size of the file is greater than my value I lost all parameters, which I passed on. I need these parameters for other functions. Is there any way to get them?

Thanks for your advice and sorry for my english.

Comment: this question isn't at all unclear, and shouldn't be closed (at least for that reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any parameters that you need to preserve even if $POST_MAX is exceeded, you need to pass them in the url, either in addition to or instead of in the post.  You can use javascript to automate this as necessary.  CGI makes url parameters available even for POST requests via the url_param() method, which otherwise works just like param().